# ContainsKey Returns false for string

Tags: c#, .net

I'm basically attempting to cache some organizations in a dictionary with their id and name. I keep getting an error: `Item with Same Key has already been added`. This is strange to me since the first if block checks if the dictionary contains the key and exits the method if it does.

Why am I getting the error given the (simplified) code below?

```
    public async Task<IList<Stat>> GetStats(DateTime start, DateTime end, string role, long tenantId)
    {
    ...
        var tasks = new List<Task>();
        foreach (var org in query)
            tasks.Add(GetOrgName(org));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        return query;

    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> Orgs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    private async Task GetOrgName(Organization org)
    {
        if (Orgs.ContainsKey(org.Id))
        {
            org.Name = Orgs[org.Id];
            return;
        }

        var result = await _directoryService.GetOrganization(org.Id);

        if (result != null)
            org.Name = result.DisplayName;
        else
            org.Name = org.Id;

        Orgs.Add(org.Id, org.Name);
    }
```

Comment: Are you running in a multi-threaded environment? `Dictionary` is not thread safe.

Comment: Multiple concurrent calls to `GetOrgName` with the same `Organization` perhaps?

Comment: Are you running in a multi-threaded environment?

Comment: @Ilian: Maybe you're onto something. I added more code to the example. The method is called with Task.WhenAll

Comment: something to do case sensitivity/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is that the dictionary is accessed by multiple tasks at the same time. So while one task is checking if the name exists another is adding it. Also since dictionary is not thread safe you might run into random exceptions with your current implementation.

If you change this:

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();
foreach (var org in query)
    tasks.Add(GetOrgName(org))
```

to:

```
foreach (var org in query)
   await GetOrgName(org);
```

You wont have that problem.

Another option would be to use a thread safe collection for the cache.
But if query contains lets say 1000 items, you code might make a thousand concurrent calls to `_directoryService.GetOrganization`. Which might be a problem?

Comment: Interesting. I had started down this route before but it seemed like foreach ignored the await. I must be mixing my js with my C#.

Answer (score 2):

This code looks dangerous

```
    if (org != null)
        org.Name = org.DisplayName;
    else
        org.Name = org.Id;
```

If `org == null` I think your `else` clause will fire `NullReference` exception. But you don't get it

Problem may be in this function

```
    var org = await _directoryService.GetOrganization(org.Id);
```

Note that this command means `org` can be modified and It may not contain its original `Id`

For example: If this never returns null value, just simple blank object You may get `Item with Same Key has already been added` exception

I think this can be fixed by double check

```
    if (!Orgs.ContainsKey(org.Id))
    {
        Orgs.Add(org.Id, org.Name);
    }
```

Comment: I had a typo on that `org != null` part. Should have been a different variable. My mistake. :) Just made edits.

Answer (score 1):

Since the dictionary is accessed by multiple threads, you should use ConcurrentDictionary instead of Dictionary. Otherwise it can happen, that two threads are trying to add the same key at the same time, leading to the exception you mentioned. Moreover, Dictionary is not thread-safe and can be corrupted if accessed by mutiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

With your latest edit, looks like it's not a multi-threaded problem but just a problem with multiple async calls - you're most likely awaiting and doing multiple queries to `GetOrganization` for the same `org.Id` when the first one hasn't finished yet (so the dictionary has not been updated yet).
So you most likely don't need `ConcurrentDictionary`. You can do something like the following instead:

```
private Dictionary<string, Task> Orgs = new Dictionary<string, Task>();

private Task GetOrgName(Organization org)
{
    Task nameTask;
    if (!Orgs.TryGetValue(org.Id, out nameTask)
    {
        nameTask = GetOrganization(.org);
        Orgs.Add(org.Id, nameTask);
    }

    return nameTask;
}

private async Task GetOrganization(Organization org)
{
    // Consider using .ConfigureAwait(false) here...
    var result = await _directoryService.GetOrganization(org.Id);
    if (result != null)
        org.Name = result.DisplayName;
    else
        org.Name = org.Id;
}
```

Note the signature for the `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

Make dictionary searching and adding to case insensitive. You can refer following:

```
private async Task GetOrgName(Organization org)
{
    if (Orgs.ContainsKey(org.Id.ToUpper()))
    {
        org.Name = Orgs[org.Id.ToUpper()];
        return;
    }

    var result = await _directoryService.GetOrganization(org.Id.ToUpper());

    if (result != null)
        org.Name = result.DisplayName;
    else
        org.Name = org.Id;

    Orgs.Add(org.Id.ToUpper(), org.Name);
}
```

Comment: To make a case-insentive Dictionary, it is better to use `new Dictionary<A, B, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` (or depending on use-case any of the other string comparers). Why? 1. the ToUpper call is easy to forget, 2. Beware of the [Turkey Test](http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html)

Comment: I just wanted to point out that he should make it case insensitive. There are several ways to achieve it. Thanks for suggesting the better one.